# Update Existing Fragment Without Flicker

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `Support.V4.App.Fragment` which I update every time `OnResume` is called.  Currently this update happens in the form of the owning `AppCompatActivity` using its `SupportFragmentManager` to `Remove` the existing `Fragment` (if any), `Replace` whatever UI element is at the `Fragment`'s site ID with a new `Fragment`, and then `Commit` the change:

```
var fragTrans = this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

// Remove existing Fragment
if (this.pcFrag != null)
{
    fragTrans.Remove(this.pcFrag);
}

// Make new Fragment
this.pcFrag = PassageContainerFragment.NewInstance(
    this.viewModel.SelectedTranslation,
    this.viewModel.RunningApp,
    this.viewModel.PassageContainer);

// Replace whatever is at Fragment site ID
fragTrans.Replace(Resource.Id.grpPassageContainer, this.pcFrag);

// Set up some fragment event handlers
this.pcFrag.ClickSelectTranslation += this.OnErrorShowingEvent(this.Frag_ClickSelectTranslation);
...

// Commit changes
fragTrans.Commit();
```

While this approach "works," there is a noticeable flicker where the UI blanks out where the old `Fragment` is removed and the new one is added.  I would like to be able to update the existing `Fragment` without destroying its `View` hierarchy, if possible.

Note: I have seen approaches that involve `Detach`ing and then re-`Attach`ing the `Fragment`, but that does not seem to work for me -- this `Fragment` has a child `Fragment` which results in an exception before the child `Fragment`'s `OnCreateView`: "No view found for fragment ID 0x1."

Is there a proper way of updating an existing fragment (e.g. calling its `OnResume`) without disturbing its `View` hierarchy?

Comment: Try look into adding a transition between the two fragments.

Comment: You can have a try with adding this line code (`fragTrans.AddToBackStack(null)`) bellow `fragTrans.Replace` .